# Order of a differential equation when the derivative expression is raised to a power.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I was a little confused on how to determine the order of a differential equation that would look something like this:

$(\frac{dy}{dx})^{4} + \frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}} + y = cos(x)$

My first intuition was that this is a non linear DE of 3rd order (since I saw the $d^{3}$ in the 2nd term), but after second thought, I feel like
$(\frac{dy}{dx})^{4} = \frac{d^{4}}{dx^{4}}(y^{4})$, which is still non linear, but would make the equation a 4th order DE.

So am I correct in saying that the ODE above would be a 4th-order, non linear DE?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of a differential equation is the largest derivative present in the differential equation. In your example, the ODE is a third order differential equation because

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^4= (y')^4$$

means that we take the first derivative of $y$ to the fourth power. This is certainly nonlinear, however it does not produce a derivative higher than the third derivative. Therefore the ODE is a third order nonlinear ODE.

As a similar example, the differential equation

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{5} + \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + 5y = \sin(x)$$

is second order since the highest derivative is $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}$. We would a call this a second order nonlinear ODE. However the differential equation

$$\frac{d^5y}{dx^5}+ \frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + 5y = \sin(x)$$

is a fifth order linear ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in general

$$y'^4 \neq \frac{d^4}{dx^4}y^4$$

Now to define the order of an ODE is done by looking at the highest order derivative which you have identified.